# How delete similar duplicates in MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to delete some "similar" row in db.

```
barcode   name    COL3
1234      item1   price10$
1234      item1   price50$
5678      item2   price10$
```

How can i delete #2 (50dlls) from db?

I tried with `MIN`, `MAX`, `DISTINCT`, `WHERE` clause but nothing.

Comment: This is a mess.

Comment: What makes you decide to delete #2? Why not #1 instead? Is there a rule? Or doesn't it matter and we can delete one or the other (only not both :-)?

Comment: What is "50dlls" supposed to mean?

Comment: i mean.... i need to delete row n.2 because i need to delete the item with higher price from db

Comment: So if barcode 0987 has prices of price8$ and price10$ you'd want to delete the price10$? and is the data stored as a string or is it just the numbers?  What is the data type of col3?  if string data max(col3) would be price8 so we have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a new table with no duplicates from the first one. You can then drop the old table and rename the new one.

```
create table new_table as
select barcode, name, min(col3) as col3
from old_table
group by barcode, name;
```

Comment: create table new_table
as (select barcode, name, min(col3) as col3
from old_table;) - 
It returns only 1st row

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `delete`:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select barcode, name, min(col3) as mincol3
          from t
          group by barcode, name)
         ) tt
         on t.barcode = tt.barcode and t.name = tt.name and t.col3 > tt.mincol3 ;
```

This assumes that `mincol3` is unique, and that the table is not too big.  The fastest method is likely to be `truncate` and re-`insert`:

```
create temporary table tt as
    select barcode, name, min(col3) as col3
    from t
    group by barcode, name;

truncate table t;

insert into t(barcode, name, col3)
    select barcode, name, col3
    from tt;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is final result. thx to all.

SELECT COL1,COL2,MIN(COL22) AS "Lowest",COL3,COL4
FROM table1
GROUP BY COL1 
Now i have all products. Important "group by"